# How to set the height knowing that under input will helper text appear in React MaterialUI v3.7?

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

As you see below, there is helper text appears under the input if invalid value in input.

But when is valid, there are no helper text.

In process of typing with validation inputs jump. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you paste the code you are using? I am assuming it's a [TextField](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/)

Answer (score 2):

Rudolf's answer is close to what you need, but the `minHeight` needs to be applied to the `TextField` (`FormControl` if using lower-level components directly) rather than `FormHelperText` because when the helper text is nil the FormHelperText component isn't displayed at all so the `minHeight` has no effect.

Here's a working example (I'm using hooks for managing state for my convenience, so this currently only works with the react alpha, but the styling approach is independent of that):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
function App(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const errorMessage = value.length === 0 ? "Please enter something" : null;
  const helperTextProps = {
    error: value.length === 0 ? true : false
  };
  const textFieldStyle = { minHeight: "5rem" };
  return (
    <div>
      <TextField label="name" style={textFieldStyle} />
      <br />
      <TextField
        label="email"
        helperText={errorMessage}
        FormHelperTextProps={helperTextProps}
        value={value}
        onChange={event => setValue(event.target.value)}
        style={textFieldStyle}
      />
      <br />
      <TextField label="other" style={textFieldStyle} />
    </div>
  );
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

And [here it is](https://codesandbox.io/s/43w36k9pp4) in a code sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [`TextField`](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/) you can pass in extra [properties for the helper text](https://material-ui.com/api/form-helper-text/):

```js
render() {
  const errorMessage = this.state.error ? "error happened" : null;
  const helperTextProps = {
    error: this.state.error ? true : false,
    style: { minHeight: "1rem" }
  };
  return (
    <TextField label="email" helperText={errorMessage} FormHelperTextProps={helperTextProps} />
  );
}
```

Note: I have not tested this code out, it's just to get the gist of it.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few years, but I stumbled upon this issue myself.  I also wanted the `minHeight` to adjust dynamically based upon the `margin` prop passed to the `TextField` component ([Here for more info](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/)). This is what I came up with - hope it helps some other folks out there.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { TextField, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

const findMinHeight = ({ margin }) =>  
    (margin && margin.toLowerCase() === 'dense') ? '4em' : '5em';

const inputBoxMinHeight = makeStyles({
    minHeightBox: {
        minHeight: findMinHeight
    }
});

const InputExample = ({ styleVariants }) => {
    const { minHeightBox } = inputBoxMinHeight(styleVariants);

    return (
        <TextField className={ minHeightBox } margin={ styleVariants.margin } />
    );
}

export default InputExample;
```